# Control on custom UITableViewCell not responding only in certain Scenes

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard, uistepper

I have a custom UITableViewCell with a Stepper inside. I've created a subclass of it, set everything up, etc.

The problem I'm having is that I just used the same custom cell on another scene and it doesn't work. I'm pretty sure I connected everything OK: outlets, delegates, etc. I am able to populate the tableView and set text on the labels and so on. The stepper seems to be inactive. 
I also tried to set its Enable property to YES on the creation of the cell, but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Out of frustration I even copy-pasted the scene where it works, deleted stuff I don't need on the new scene and changed its class to match that of the TableViewController for the new scene. Doesn't make a difference either.

I'm running out of ideas. Any help would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The stepper could be outside the bounds of its superview (if the constraints aren't set up properly), which would make it inactive. Try giving a background color to the superview (whatever that is) to see if this is true (or set the superview's clipsToBounds property to yes which will clip any part of the stepper that's out of bounds).

Comment: Yeah, this is what I thought and it's also why I copy-pasted the cell from the other scene. Nontheless, I've tried your suggestions to not avail. Thanks though.

Comment: Are the minimum and maximum values set properly for the stepper (I'm not sure if all the attributes of an object are copied or not)?

Comment: I was trying this right now. As it turns out, I set them on code. I commented out these lines and it works. I still don't know what conflicts with waht, but now I know where to look. If you write this as an answer, I'll check it as answered. Thanks!

Comment: BTW, we have similar backgrounds. I'm also an organic chemist...

Comment: Well, found it. I created a custom object to store the properties of the custom cell. As it turns out I added the property maximumValue twice instead of adding maximumValue and minimumValue. So the minimum value was set on storyboard to 0 whereas the maximum was set on code to 0. That was embarassing. Thanks again for your pointers @rdelmar !

Comment: Cool to find another organic chemist! I think we're probably a rare breed here on SO.